# My SQL Server Analysis services won't switch from tabular to multidimensional

Tags: ssas, olap, ssas-tabular, olap-cube, multidimensional-cube

I'm trying to switch the sql server analysis services to multidimensional since I'm getting an error in visual studio when I try to deploy my analysis project that says I can't deploy the model because the deployment server is not running in multidimensional mode. I tryed switching the deployment mode to 0 in my msmdsrv.ini file, but that did not change the outcome. I did restart the service already, but that didn't work either.This is the error I get:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My SQL Server Analysis services won't switch from tabular to multidimensional

There are 2 possible ways to fix this, first is the recommended way and second is shortcut.

- Uninstall and Reinstall **SQL Server Analysis Services** feature. On the **Analysis Services Configuration** step of the installation wizard, go to **Server Configuration** tab and select the **Multi-dimensional and Data Mining Mode** option button.
- Change `msmdsrv.ini` file. Change the line `<DeploymentMode>2</DeploymentMode>` in the file ('2' refers to tabular and '0' refers to multidimensional) to `<DeploymentMode>0</DeploymentMode>`. Following that, restart the analysis server.

Comment: Already fixed it by just reinstalling SQL Server Analysis Services indeed, switching the deployment mode from 2 to 0 didn't solve the problem for me unfortunately.